# Confusion with system clock change in messages?

Tags: log, time

In the messages log I can see that my system clock was changed. This was recorded in the log happening at 4pm and the change was to move the system clock to 3.58pm. However, in the next lines of the log they are still recorded as happening at 4pm and not the new time the system clock was changed to - surely the events following should be recorded at the new system clock time?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: It might be logging the events before the change (I know a few daemons that do that)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the system clock is adjusted with small incremental updates until the correct time is reached.